# Variation of Relative Humidity (RH) in closed room vs outside

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, everyday-life, ideal-gas, humidity

I have an insulated garage room with the doors closed, and I am interested to monitor the Temperature + Relative Humidity (RH) inside the room, compared with outside.  I have taken some readings inside the room and outside, but I am having trouble interpreting the results - I don't understand the physics.

Here are the measurements (Red is inside and Blue is outside) for T and RH, plus a plot of *calculated* absolute humidity (g/m3), derived from T and RH

[image]

**My Expectation**
Absolute Humidity remains roughly equal between the two spaces.  RH inside and outside varies inversely with temperature.

**My Observation**
RH outside varies with temperature as expected; but inside it remains relatively constant with temperature changes.  This means that when Absolute Humidity inside is calculated, it appears that moisture is being added to the air as the temperature is increased.  To be clear, there is no obvious source that adds moisture in the room; its just a relatively empty storage space.

**My Question**
Can anyone explain the physics behind my observation (ie, constant RH in a room with varying temperature)?

EDIT: I disagree this question is about engineering. I have taken some measurements of the world, and I seek to explain them - isn't that science?  My fundamental question is: Is there a physical explanation for my observations?